# Get value from stdClass Object within stdClass Object using foreach loop

Tags: php

I have the following part of PHP object class:

```
stdClass Object ( 
[data] => Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
[id] => 1194760
```

.....

I am trying to extract all values for `id`. When I echo `$cronJobUrlList->data[0]->id` I do get a value but only for the first. When I try the following nothing is returned.

```
foreach ($cronJobUrlList->data as $data) {
    foreach ($data->id as $cronId) {
        echo $cronId;
    }
}
```

I would like to obtain the `id` value for every entry. I never worked with object classes before.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `foreach ($cronJobUrlList->data as $data) {
        echo $data->id;
}` ?

Comment: @AlanMachado it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access an object inside the array index. Once you iterate over the array, every instance will return an object and you only need to call for its property, so you don't have to iterate over the value again.

```
foreach ($cronJobUrlList->data as $data) {
    echo $data->id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
foreach ($cronJobUrlList->data as $key=> $data) {
       echo $data->id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you convert your object to an array using `json_encode()`.

And then decode using `json_decode()`.

From there you can get your `id` key easily.

The [second argument to `json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) forces the JSON to unserialize to an associative array if it is truthy (it is falsy by default).

That is, use `json_decode($json, true)`